# Using Shark to profile an iPhone game, pressing "Start" doesn't do anything

Tags: iphone, profiling, shark

I've done a decent amount of reading about how to profile iPod applications using Shark, and all works well until I try to click "Start" (and nothing happens).  I've tried profiling an individual process (app), all processes, and it doesn't seem to Start.  This tutorial is one place that I used to set it up (so I think I'm following all the steps):

http://rudifa.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/profiling-an-iphone-application-with-shark/

(I've also rebooted my mac and iPod)

Anyone have any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shark support has been dropped on iOS 4. Official Apple position can be seen here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/243237

They expect you to use Instruments and Time Profiler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Time Profiler instrument?  Apple seems to be moving in that direction.

Comment: Well, never found out the exact reason why it was failing.  I ended up reimaging my iPod, and trying Time Profiler within Instruments, and it worked (and provides exactly what I need!  Thanks).  So original problem not solved, but wiping iPod and using Time Profiler instrument works great.